# Angular2 ActivatedRoute parameter is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Am trying to display the value of activate route param in the screen but fails

In the first component i have

```
<ul *ngFor="let cate of categories;">
  <li (click)="onviewChecklists(cate.id)">
     <a> {{i+1}} {{cate.category}} </a>
  </li>

</ul>

  onviewChecklists(category:string){
     this._router.navigate(["tsafety/checklist-management/categories/items",
       {category:category}])
 }
```

Now on the second component to where am naviagting i have

```
category:any;

constructor(
private _router:Router,private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute
 ) {

 }

ngOnInit() {

   this.category = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['category'];
   console.log(this.category);  //this works
} 
//on this component html {{category}} returns only the first param
```

In the second component html file when i `{{category}}` it onl displays the value of the first routing that is

```
navigate 1 param is checklist display is checklist
navigate 2 param is newcheck  display is checklist
```

What could be wrong since the `console.log()` prints the correct value but `{{category}}` only prints the first value

In the second component ive aso tried

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.onGetItems(+this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['category']);

 }

 onGetItems(category){
    return this._checklistitemsService.getAllItems(category)
    .subscribe(
       res=>{
         this.checklistitems = res
    }
  )
```

The onGetItems method is called only once

Comment: Can you clarify what you see on screen and what you see in console log.

Comment: An example when i nevigate with param checklist screen print is checklist, when i navigate with param newcheck screen print is still checklist but console.log() prints the actual value

Comment: This behavior suggests something is wrong with your bindings. Make sure that `category` is properly bound in your second component. It sounds like the variable in the template is bound to something other than the variable in the component.

Comment: category is a variable in the second component

Comment: Ive updated the question with where navigtion click is done could this be the cause

Comment: #adam ive tried adding a http method but its only executed once which means nothing is wrong with the bindings

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When ever you are passing a route parameter, and raise a service call using that parameter, you should use an **`Observable<params>`** to subscribe to the activated route in your constructor as below

```
category: number = 0;
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, 
            private checklistitemsService: CheckListItemsService) {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

            this.category = + params['category'];
              ......

    });
}
```

Then your service call should be made in the ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit(){
      this._checklistitemsService.getAllItems(category)
          .subscribe(res => {
                          this.checklistitems = res
           }
}
```

**Mistake:**

If you are retrieving the route params in **ngOnInit**, your components will be loaded before the route value is fetched, so you will find explicit delay and so your **this.checklistitems** remains without value.

**My solution:**

By **retrieving the route parameters, in the constructor**, **ngOnInit** will not execute until the route parameter is retrieved and there by making a service call to get this.checklistitems. Now your component loads correctly.

Comment: was the explanation made sense?

Comment: Yes it did, ive actually realized the mistake was retrieving value on OnInit