# how to get :id param into the service of angular2 using routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for a way to pass mac id into service using routes to filter data.
In my app.html i have a dropdown menu, in which i have a list of mac address displayed(manually written).Using angular activated routes how to get the mac id into the angular services so that i can use it in a filter method.

[app.html]

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">

      <li><a routerLink="mac/:id">3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-33</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="mac/:id">3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-34</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="mac/:id">3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-35</a></li> 

</ul>
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TabuleService {

  //private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private _Url = 'http://localhost:3000';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
     private _http: Http,
     private route: ActivatedRoute ) {}



getTemperature(): Observable<testing\[\]> {
    const url = this._Url+'/temperature';                    
    return this._http.get(url)
               .map(res =>{
                let data=res.json();
                let parsedData = \[\]; 
 // here i need to get parameter of mac from the routes to filter
                data.filter(function(el){ return el.mac=="3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-35" }) 

                .forEach(function(item){ parsedData.push({ 
                          x:item.epoch_time_stamp, y:parseFloat(item.temp) });  });
                          //console.log(parsedData);
                return parsedData; })
               .catch(this.handleError);
               }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 ActivatedRoute parameter is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323644/angular2-activatedroute-parameter-is-undefined)

Comment: I can't understand anything to what you want to achieve. First of all, if you want to pass an ID through a link, the ID should be part of the link. You always pass `:id`, instead of passing the actual ID: `routerLink="mac/3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-33"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu  scrollable-menu" role="menu">

      <li *ngFor="address in macAddress>
             <a  [routerLink]="['/mac', address]">
                 {{address}}
             </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

In your component,

```
macAddress:Array<string>=['3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-33', '3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-34', '3s-ds-23-sf-23-ce-35';
```

You cannot get the parameter using

```
 constructor(
     private _http: Http,
     private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
           this.mac= this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                   this.category = + params['address'];


    });
 }
```