# Getting route params on initial page load

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get route parameters for the first time, and I can't seem to figure out how to use `ActivatedRoute` properly.

Based on the API and docs, I'm trying this to get my route params on page load.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const orgSlug: Observable<string> = this.route.params.map(params => {console.log(params); return params.org});
}
```

On page load, nothing gets logged. My assumption would have been on the page load, I would get the initial state of the params object. I tried it both in the `ngOnInit` and the constructor with no results in either. I know I can check snapshot, but then I'd have to have duplicate code for the initial state and any changed state, which feels wrong.

Am I misunderstanding how observables or the ActivatedRoute works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use subscribe() after the params.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id']; // do this if it is a number +params['id']

    });
  }
```

Also, you may want to unsubscribe to it ( optional )

```
private sub:any;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id']; // do this if it is a number +params['id']

    });
  }
```

And unsubscribe to it when your component is about to destroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Though angular will do the garbage collection for you, it is still better to unsubscribe to it manually just to be safe.

Comment: That's what I thought I should be doing, but the docs show mapping to it directly; for some reason I thought it would let me make sure of the information that way, but I realize now that only creates a new observable that I'd have to map to which may or may not be what I want to do?).

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the constructor and you should subscribe to the params, which  will be executed before the page is rendered and your params will be available , since these are async calls putting it in the onInit is not advisable

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {  
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

         console.log(params);

    }).map(params => {
           console.log(params); 
           return params.org}
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was confused why the docs went straight to map instead of subscribing; I get that params is a behavior subject, but still... Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by **behavior subject**

Comment: When I log params, it shows up as a BehaviorSubject, a subject that emits it's current value on subscription, then continues to emit on following `next`s?

Comment: Can you refer this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323644/angular2-activatedroute-parameter-is-undefined/42324758#42324758)

Comment: What you've mentioned is already the answer I'm looking for, I was just trying to see if you knew why the docs don't get the values that way.

Comment: if you find the docs to have mistake quote the example and raise a issue against the docs in github.