# Observable<> is not assignable to type Observable<>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, observable

I am trying to create a Task Manager app where the user can click on a certain project and view the tasks (project info) under the said project.

The project is saved in firestore and being fetched from firestore.

I keep running into a runtime error where it does not allow the program to build properly.

Attached are all the files.

firestore.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { promise } from 'protractor';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { iClientName } from '../models/signup.interface';
import { iCreateProject } from '../models/createproject.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirestoreService {
  constructor(public firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

  AddclientName(clientName: string, clientSurname: string): Promise<void> {
    const id = this.firestore.createId();

    return this.firestore.doc(`clientNameList/${id}`).set({
      id,
      clientName,
      clientSurname,
    });
  }

  CreateNewProjectSubmit(
    projectName: string,
    projectDescription: string,
    projectDeadline: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    const id = this.firestore.createId();
    const projectNumberOfTasks = 0;

    return this.firestore.doc(`projectList/${id}`).set({
      id,
      projectName,
      projectDescription,
      projectDeadline,
      projectNumberOfTasks,
    });
  }

  displayProjects(): Observable<iCreateProject[]> {
    return this.firestore
      .collection<iCreateProject>(`projectList`)
      .valueChanges();
  }

  getProjectInfo(projectId: string): Observable<iCreateProject> {
    return this.firestore
      .collection('projectList')
      .doc<iCreateProject>(projectId)
      .valueChanges();
  }
}
```

project-info.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { iCreateProject } from '../models/createproject.interface';
import { ProjectTasksPage } from '../project-tasks/project-tasks.page';
import { FirestoreService } from '../services/firestore.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-info',
  templateUrl: './project-info.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-info.page.scss'],
})
export class ProjectInfoPage implements OnInit {
  public createProject: iCreateProject;

  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const projectId: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.firestoreService
      .getProjectInfo(projectId)
      .subscribe((createProject) => {
        this.createProject = createProject;
      });
  }

  projectTasks() {
    this.modalController
      .create({ component: ProjectTasksPage })
      .then((modalElement) => modalElement.present());
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
[ng] Error: src/app/services/firestore.service.ts:49:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<iCreateProject | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<iCreateProject>'.
[ng]   Type 'iCreateProject | undefined' is not assignable to type 'iCreateProject'.
[ng]     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'iCreateProject'.
[ng]
[ng] 49     return this.firestore
[ng]        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 50       .collection('projectList')
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 51       .doc<iCreateProject>(projectId)
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 52       .valueChanges();
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] × Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Try changing the return type of `getProjectInfo` to `Observable<iCreateProject | undefined>`

Comment: Seems like `this.firestore.collection('projectList').doc<iCreateProject>(projectId)` may return `undefined` if the document is not found, doing what @ChrisGilardi suggests may solve your problem

Comment: I do that - but then I get the following error 
Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.
FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.

Comment: What you now mention seems to be a different issue. The route parameter is not yet set in the `ngOnInit`. You might want to use the `paramMap` Observable which is offered by the `ActivatedRoute` (`route.paramMap`). For more information, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42324758/7870650).